# Varnish Cache on Memcached

Tags: memcached, varnish

I'd like to know if is possible to use memcached as the default storage for Varnish cache. 
Searching on the web I found https://github.com/sodabrew/libvmod-memcached but the examples that I found so far was just about manually storing/retrieving the content on memcached using VCL rules.

What I'm looking for is memcached as the default storage for Varnish, just like we do with file/memory today.

Is there some way to do this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [architecture document](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ArchitectNotes) on Varnish. You can see the designer had specific ideas on the backend (all in memory, let the kernel decide what goes to swap/disk). Memcache doesn't really fit there. Can you explain why Varnish as-is is insufficient, and you want memcache as the back-end of varnish?

If you want a front-end cache based on memcache, there are probably other solutions or you could write one. I wouldn't pick Varnish just for the VCL language, as I think it's a complex language to accomplish proper caching.

Comment: Just an update. I have a cluster and I'd like to keep cache on memory and share this cache between the Varnish instances. Now I'm thinking on something like NFS and keep cache on disk. After your comment I took a look at the doc and could understand why memcached is not a proper storage for what I had in mind.